# IEnumerable View has null value in Controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have a Strongly typed view of Type `IEnumerable<MVC.Models.Product>`. I am receiving null values when i iterate through the IEnumerable in the controller.

**View**

```
    @model IEnumerable<MVC.Models.Product>
   <h2>Product</h2>
    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {

      using (Html.BeginForm("AddToCart", "Home"))
        {
               @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ProductID)
            <div>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ProductName)
            </div>
            <div>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ProductVendor)
            </div>
            <div>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ProductDesc)
            </div>
            <div>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.productPrice)
            </div>
            <div>
                @Html.TextBox("Quant")
            </div>
            <div>
                <button type="submit" value="Add to cart">Add to cart</button>
            </div>
        }

    }
```

**Controller**

```
     public ActionResult Index(int? page)
    {
        using (AutoPartsSystemEntities3 db = new Models.AutoPartsSystemEntities3())
        {
            var Query = db.Products;
            int pageSize = 3;
            int pageNumber = (page ?? 1);
            return View(Query.OrderBy(e => e.ProductName).ToPagedList(pageNumber,pageSize));
        }

    }

    public ActionResult Product(int id)
    {
        using (AutoPartsSystemEntities3 db = new AutoPartsSystemEntities3())
        {
            var Query = (from p in db.Products
                        where p.ProductID == id
                        select p).ToList();

            return View(Query);
        }
    }
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult AddToCart(IEnumerable<Product> p, int Quant)
    {
        double TotalPrice = 0;
        int ProductID = 0;
        foreach (Product pro in p)
        {
            TotalPrice = pro.productPrice * Quant;
            ProductID = pro.ProductID;
        }
        using (AutoPartsSystemEntities8 db = new AutoPartsSystemEntities8())
        {
            db.Carts.Add(new Cart { ProductId = ProductID, CheckOut = false, DateCreated = DateTime.Now, Price = (float)TotalPrice, Quantity = Quant, UserId = 1 });
            db.SaveChanges();

        }
        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
    }
```

**Product Class**

```
public partial class Product
{
    public int ProductID { get; set; }
    public string ProductName { get; set; }
    public string ProductVendor { get; set; }
    public string ProductDesc { get; set; }
    public double productPrice { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: do you get the null in the GET action or in the POST (the function you posted)?
In your view you are creating many forms..

Comment: @KirkWoll I have added index controller

Comment: @RoelantM in the POST action

Comment: You creating a form for each item in your collection which makes so sense (you can only submit one form at a time. And your `foreach` loop is generating `name` attributes that have no relationship to your model (your also generating duplicate `id` attributes which is invalid html). Use one form and add a property for the quantity to your model then refer [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30094047/html-table-to-ado-net-datatable/30094943#30094943)

Comment: @StephenMuecke I have made those changes but it still dint help

Comment: What changes? Your code makes no sense. You need one form and inside that for a `for` loop of `EditorTemplate` as per the link in the previous comment. And your POST method needs to be `public ActionResult AddToCart(List<Product> model)`

Comment: And I have just rolled back your edit. You cannot completely change your question (the other answers and comments would make no sense). And you need to generate form controls if you want to post back values (`DisplayFor()` does not generate an input)

Comment: @StephenMuecke I don't want  the result in a textbox, I want it just to be displayed in the screen. When the button is clicked, The Quantity and object is sent to the controller

Comment: You cannot send your model to the controller if you do not create inputs for each property of your model! (use hidden inputs if necessary). But in any case you should only be submitting the ID of the product and the quantity

Comment: @JagajagaBagabaga - You've made a few statements, shown some code, but you haven't asked us a question.

Answer (score 0):

Each form is sending back a single MVC.Models.Product, not a Collection (IEnumerable). Try:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult AddToCart(Product p, int Quant)
```

And modfiy the controller to refect the fact that you're only saving one product at a time.

and add:

```
@Html.HiddenFor(modelItem => item.ProductID)
```

under the displayFor for it so it posts back.

Comment: I have tried that first, but it's storing 0's in the database

Comment: Ah, I see. Right you are3. I edited the code so that your productId gets sent back to the controller.